# Does a one-to-one function need to have every element in its domain have a corresponding element in the range?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The definition of a one-to-one function is such that no two elements in the domain are mapped into the same element in the range. Mathematically:

$$
\forall a,b \in A, \;\; f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b
$$

However I am wondering if there can be elements $a,b \in A$ that are never sent out. In other words, they do not have a corresponding mapping in the range. Is this possible? thanks.

Comment: No that's not possible.

Comment: Technically, a function that is not defined for every element in its domain is called a *partial function*.

Comment: @chepner: More importantly, a function that is not defined for every element in its domain is not a function.

Comment: @chepner never heard of it before but I'm just curious: wouldn't this definition be totally meaningless?

Comment: Why would it be meaningless? Was the square root "function" completely meaningless before the invention/discovery of the complex numbers? In some sense, there isn't much difference between saying the square root is a partial function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ and saying it is a total function with domain $\{ a | a \in \mathbb{R}, a \ge 0 \}$.

Comment: @chepner I think you just made Vim's point: there isn't much difference between the square root partial function and square root total function.  In fact, the total function gives more information because it specifies the domain exactly.  I am curious if there is any situation where the notion of partial function is actually useful.

Comment: Partial functions are important for defining programming language semantics. A simple function like `head` (which returns the first element of a list) is partial, because it is not defined for empty lists. Languages deal with this issue in a variety of ways; allow the partial function to fail, define a total function by enriching the return type, or define a total function by restricting the domain.

Comment: @chepner Ah very neat, thanks for the info

Comment: I will concede that I don't know if the concept of partial functions is relevant to real analysis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition, the domain of a function $f$ is the set of elements which are "sent out" by $f$, so this is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

No Because Function would  Not be  Well defined in that case,So it is not even a valid function.

Answer (score 4):

A function which is not defined for every element of its domain is called a partial function. One can *define* a notion of a [partial bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection#Generalization_to_partial_functions), which is a function for which $f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$ holds when $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are actually defined.

Answer (score 4):

The "domain of a *function*" is by definition the set of all things that are "sent out"; hence this cannot happen.

But "domain of a *partial function*" has as a subset the set of all things that are "sent out".

Suppose $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, and $f(3)=3$. That defines a one-to-one *function* whose domain is the set $\{1,2,3\}$.

But it also defines a one-to-one *partial function* whose domain is $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

And a **different** one-to-one *partial function* whose domain is $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.